# ASP NET MVC медленно работает сайт

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Имеется сайт MVC+ БД MySQL - все это вертится на хостинге reg.ru. Настроена авторизация, по имени и паролю. Все настройки - возможности по умолчанию ASP net MVC. Так же реализовано API для взаимодействия с мобильным приложением.
В API есть несколько методов: а) получить ссылку по лицевому счету; б)обновить базу некоторыми значениями.
Раньше не так обращал внимания, но сейчас, переход между страницами может длится несколько секунд, причем, та страница которую пытаюсь открыть либо просто пустая (обычный текст html), либо страница с обычным отображением модели из БД. к примеру такой есть метод в контроллере.

```
public ViewResult List(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.LS = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "ls_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.Tel = sortOrder == "Tel" ? "tel_desc" : "Tel";
        ViewBag.Email = sortOrder == "Email" ? "email_desc" : "Email";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        var contacts = from a in db.ListKontacts select a;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            contacts = contacts.Where(s => s.Tel.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.Email.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.Ls.Contains(searchString));
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "ls_desc":
                contacts = contacts.OrderByDescending(s => s.Ls);
                break;
            case "tel_desc":
                contacts = contacts.OrderBy(s => s.Tel);
                break;
            case "email_desc":
                contacts = contacts.OrderByDescending(s => s.Email);
                break;
            default:  // Name ascending 
                contacts = contacts.OrderBy(s => s.Ls);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        return View(contacts.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));           
    }
```

В мобильном приложении тоже выполняются медленно запросы. Чисто ради интереса, запросы к localhost и основному сайту, время выполнения одного и того же запроса, с одним и тем же набором данных выполнялся 0,2мс и 8-13с соответственно. Также заметил, что и в дебаге (в локалхосте) происходит подтупливание с открытием страниц.
Может можно как-то ускорить открытие страниц? может в web.config нужно что дописать? Если что, прошу прощения за возможно глупые вопросы.

Comment: Вам не кажется, что просто на хостинге мало ресурсов? Вы же знаете, что такое "шаред" хостинг и что такое "оверселлинг"? А если вам хочется подробнее понять, где у вас основные тормоза - профилируйте приложение ([тынц1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms182372.aspx), [тынц2](https://habrahabr.ru/post/98361/)).

Comment: Если он еще и на локалхосте подтупливает - что-то не так с ToPagedList